# Delete From Statement in SQL 2014 Failing

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that does some clean up on a database each morning.  This is a Connectwise database (Company CRM) which we have access for reporting.  It currently lives on a VM Server 2012 in Microsoft Azure.  In a nutshell this stored procedure combines data from multiple records into one record and deletes all the combined records.

Background into the issue experienced.  We are deleting a record from one table (parent), there are several other tables (child) with foreign keys to this table and they have not been setup with the cascade delete option.  Our Stored Procedure goes through each one of the other child tables and deletes the records relating to the parent table.  Turns out this script started failing in February and we are just now noticing (smh).

Error Message Received -

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure  Alter_SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value, Line 53 [Batch Start Line 93]
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
    delete
    from    
        SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value
    where
        SR_Service_RecID in (   select 
                                    (s.SR_Service_RecID)
                                from
                                    SR_Service s
                                join SR_Board sb on sb.SR_Board_RecID=s.SR_Board_RecID
                                where sb.Board_Name like 'Collections' 
                                    and s.SR_Status_RecID != 511
                                    and cast(trim(left(right(s.Summary, len(s.Summary) - charindex('#',s.Summary)),5))as int)=@invoiceNumber
                            )
        and SR_Service_RecID != (   select 
                                        min (s.SR_Service_RecID)
                                    from
                                        SR_Service s
                                    join SR_Board sb on sb.SR_Board_RecID=s.SR_Board_RecID
                                    where sb.Board_Name like 'Collections' 
                                        and s.SR_Status_RecID != 511
                                        and cast(trim(left(right(s.Summary, len(s.Summary) - charindex('#',s.Summary)),5))as int)=@invoiceNumber
                                )
                                )
```

SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value Table (1st column is an primary key, second and third are foreign keys):

| SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value_RecID | SR_Service_RecID | User_Defined_Field_RecID | User_Defined_Field_Value | Last_Update_UTC | Updated_By |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5791 | 8009 | 30 | ENGR | 2022-04-18 | jgriffin |
| 5792 | 8009 | 51 | NO | 2022-04-18 | jgriffin |
| 5789 | 8240 | 30 | ENGR | 2022-04-18 | jgriffin |
| 5790 | 8240 | 51 | NO | 2022-04-18 | jgriffin |
| 5787 | 8420 | 30 | ENGR | 2022-04-18 | jgriffin |
| 5788 | 8420 | 51 | NO | 2022-04-18 | jgriffin |

Troubleshooting to date:

1. I have simplified the delete statement to just delete based off of SR_Service_RecIDs without the additional select subqueries with no luck.
2. I have tried to delete multiple records by SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value_RecID using the in statement with no luck.  Where SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value_RecID in (5789,5787).
3. I could delete using the in statement with just one recid in the list. Where SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value_RecID in (5789).
4. I updated the FK SR_service_RecID to use cascade delete.  I then tried to delete the one parent record and received the same error.

Trigger on this table:

```
  -- Code for delete 
  if exists(select * from deleted) and not exists(Select * from inserted)
begin 
    INSERT INTO [TruCWHistorian].[dbo].[CWHistorian]( [Table], [Object_RecID], [FieldName], [Old_Value], [New_Value], [Date_Updated], [Updated_By])
    SELECT 
        'SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value',
        d.SR_Service_RecID,
        u.Caption,
        (select User_Defined_Field_Value FROM deleted),
        '', -- no new value for deleted record case 
        getDate(),
        '' -- no record of who made change in this case 
    FROM    
        deleted d
    join User_Defined_Field u on u.User_Defined_Field_RecID=d.User_Defined_Field_RecID
end
```

Comment: The error *is* telling you the problem here; what about the error don't you understand? There are plenty of duplicate questions about this error too; what about those didn't you understand?

Comment: It's not DELETE that's failing, it's the complex filter conditions and the error explains why. Those conditions assume the subqueries will only return a single value. In this case, they returned multiple values. Fix the query to either check for existence or return a single value

Comment: Well, is `Alter_SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value` a trigger? Did you look at _that_ code? I bet it's [this bug](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/). Also, don't use cascade because it has way too many limitations.

Comment: @Larnu this appears to be a generic response and doesn't help me understand the problem.  The following doesn't work either.  Delete from table where column in (5787,5798).

Comment: I would put good money on Aaron's guess of a wayward trigger too, as the query as posted doesn't seem capable of producing this error (one subquery is used with `IN` and the other can only result in at most a single value).

Comment: Show us the output of `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo. Alter_SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value'));` because that's where your bug is. Also get in the habit of [using a schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: @AaronBertrand it is a trigger.  That is good information.  I am following this bug now to see if it resolves.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the result of that is NULL.

Comment: Are you sure you're running it in the right database? Is your trigger/table in a schema other than `dbo`? (Again this is why you should always be explicit.)

Comment: appears the trigger updates another db on the same server.  It doesn't appear to have the bug listed above.  I will post the trigger outside of the comments.

Comment: I have added the schema prefix with no success either.

Comment: cleary related to the trigger.  I disabled the trigger and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your trigger, this subquery is causing the problem (and there's no reason for it anyway, since with no correlation it returns *all the rows* from `deleted`):

```
(select User_Defined_Field_Value FROM deleted)
```

Why isn't it just:

```
INSERT INTO [TruCWHistorian].[dbo].[CWHistorian](...)
SELECT 
    'SR_Service_User_Defined_Field_Value',
    d.SR_Service_RecID,
    u.Caption,
    d.User_Defined_Field_Value,
    '', -- no new value for deleted record case 
    getDate(),
    '' -- no record of who made change in this case 
FROM    
    deleted d
...
```

Comment: Your support was spot on and greatly appreciated.  I would have not thought to look at the trigger.  I am not sure why our programmer that wrote that did it that way.  In the trigger for the insert he did in fact use inserted.User_Defined_Field_Value :)

Comment: Probably because s/he wrote the insert/update logic in the same manner, found the problem with insert/update and corrected it but never tried to delete more than a single row at a time. It is an extremely common mistake in trigger writing - assuming a single row exists in the virtual inserted and deleted tables.